# Modify MSIL in a plug-in dll at runtime

Tags: .net, reflection, cil

We have a .NET plug-in mechanism, but our SDK isn't frozen yet so we make breaking changes every now and again. Sometimes these only amount to a change in casing or fixing a naming convention.

So, question; how hard is it to go into a dll before or after it's loaded and change the msil so that trivial SDK breakages can be fixed at runtime?

Comment: If you have access to the dll before it is loaded by the runtime, you can use Mono.Cecil to modify it, as Diego suggets. I know a couple of users who use it to deal with breaking changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is invariably too late after it is loaded.  The JIT compiler would quite likely already have converted the method bodies to machine code.  Especially on Mono.  The DLL is locked, you can't hack it anymore.  Using [the profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188743.aspx) is pretty difficult to justify.

Leverage Edit + Continue if this is important.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it would be very difficult if not unfeasible.

Answer (score 4):

[Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) might help you.